# Rails very slow load each time stylesheet in asset is modified

Tags: ruby-on-rails

each time i modified my rails stylesheet, it will load very long in development mode.

this is the log and as you can see, the loading takes 90seconds, an average time for each asset modifications.

please help to advise what are the possible issues.

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2017-12-27 17:54:35 +0800
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
[1m[35mCart Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 110]]
[1m[36mAddnew Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "addnews".* FROM "addnews"  ORDER BY "addnews"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m
[1m[35mProduct Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
[1m[36mAddnew Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "addnews".* FROM "addnews"  ORDER BY "addnews"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1[0m
[1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
[1m[36mAddnew Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "addnews".* FROM "addnews"  ORDER BY "addnews"."id" ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2[0m
[1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (1.0ms)
[1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = ?[0m  [["cart_id", 110]]
[1m[35mLineItem Exists (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["cart_id", 110]]
[1m[36mLineItem Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."cart_id" = ?[0m  [["cart_id", 110]]
Rendered layouts/_header_cart_in_total.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_header_cart.html.erb (13.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_home_header.html.erb (34.0ms)
Rendered shared/_flash.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 90627ms (Views: 90615.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application-46823b452df5e3c7c6257626147e5cf2aa1e9b157ec4229dc94afc4bcb358ad8.css" for ::1 at 2017-12-27 17:56:06 +0800
```

development.rb parameters uploaded as per requested.
rails version is 4.2.4, ruby version is 2.3.3.

```
Rails.application.configure do


# In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
# every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
# since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
config.cache_classes = false

# Do not eager load code on boot.
config.eager_load = false


config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true


config.action_mailer.show_previews = true
# Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
config.active_support.deprecation = :log

# Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

config.assets.debug = false

# Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
# yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
config.assets.digest = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true


config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
host = 'localhost:3000'
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port                 => '587',
  :authentication       => :plain,
  :user_name            => ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
  :password             => ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"],
  :domain               => 'localhost:3000',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
# Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
# Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
# Raises helpful error messages.
config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

# Raises error for missing translations
# config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

# Enable the asset pipeline
end
```

Comment: It's because your assets precompile again when you modify the files. Make sure run **RAILS_ENV=development rake assets:precompile** if your env is development.

Comment: hi thanks, but after apply the code, it does load fast but does not shows the CSS changes in development after i refresh page for each changes to see the effect, please advise

Comment: Please let me know which version of rails you are using and development config parameter values.

Comment: added in post above, thanks..

Answer (score 2):

You can improve asset speed in development.
First of all, make sure that CACHING IS ON.

Open this file config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Then restart your server.

Assets may compile slowly, but at least make them compile slowly only once, not every time. To ensure assets are cached, make sure caching is on.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it is 'true' all the while but problem still persist. Each time when reload page after changing the stylesheet to see the effect, it will still take very long time..